# Elastic Search High Level Java Client UpdateByQueryRequest API help required

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am migrating from normal ES Http calls to ES HighLevelJavaClient.

I want to convert this old implementation  **POST** /*_update_by_query*

```
 {
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.collibra_match_for = []"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['collibra_match_for.keyword'].values.length > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To High Level client code.

The code I tried is :

```
  UpdateByQueryRequest request = new UpdateByQueryRequest();
    request.setConflicts("proceed");
    request.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("doc['collibra_match_for.keyword'].values.length > 0"))));
    request.setScript(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless","ctx._source.collibra_match_for = []",Collections.emptyMap()));
    request.setRefresh(true);
    try {
        BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = esClient.updateByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        long totalDocs = bulkResponse.getTotal();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=exception, reason=Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_update_by_query?requests_per_second=-1&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&refresh=true&conflicts=proceed&timeout=1m] and method [POST], allowed: [DELETE, PUT, GET, HEAD]]
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: Hey @Dennis I edited the question ,please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the answer to this question..
We just need to add the index name in the constructor. 
This is the final answer to the question.Hope it will be useful to someone in future :)

```
    UpdateByQueryRequest request = new UpdateByQueryRequest(INDEX_NAME);
    request.setConflicts("proceed");
    request.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("doc['collibra_match_for.keyword'].values.length > 0"))));
    request.setScript(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless","ctx._source.collibra_match_for = []",Collections.emptyMap()));
    request.setRefresh(true);
    try {
        BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = esClient.updateByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        long totalDocs = bulkResponse.getTotal();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```